# What version of Windows does MySQL 5.5 support

Tags: mysql

As the question suggest I need to know what versions of Windows Server will MySQL 5.5 run on. I have looked online but cannot find much for 5.5. The version 5.7 seems to be run on Windows Server 2016 and higher right up to 2022.

I have to use MySQL 5.5 as that is what the vendor of the program has said.

If you have a link to any information saying what version of windows Server MySQL 5.5 will run on I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks for any help

Comment: An old one? :-) Sorry that was not meant to be nasty (and welcome to dba.se BTW). MySQL 5.5 is EOL for > 2.5 years now - so why are you running it?

Comment: Because the vendor of one of our systems only supports up to 5.5. and we need to move to windows 2016 or 2019 server.

Comment: Well, it went EOL in 2018, so 2016 should work for you - I don't really know - this is just a guess. I would suggest though that, in future, you have a clause written into your supply contracts whereby your supplier is obliged to use current versions of software. This is a frequently recurring problem we get here!

Comment: MySQL has "always" run on "all" Windows versions.  (It even runs on Atari, I think.)

Answer (score 1):

According to Archive.org's copy of https://www.mysql.com/support/supportedplatforms/database.html from 2018 (https://web.archive.org/web/20180721014307/https://www.mysql.com/support/supportedplatforms/database.html), the supported Windows platforms for MySQL 5.5 were:

- Windows 8
- Windows 10
- Windows Server 2012 R2
- Windows Server 2016

[image: screenshot of a portion of Supported Platforms table]

Comment: Great thank you everyone for your help.

Comment: If the answer was helpful, you can help others by voting it up and/or accepting it. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers for more information about this.